# Re-tag option for Community Wiki questions is missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

Shouldn't there be a re-tag option, for community questions?  Users can still re-tag questions by going through the edit menu.

Like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/42143/where-can-i-use-windows-7-math-input-panel) question.

[image: added screenshot:]
EDIT: I have both buttons[image: Normal question]

Comment: No, the "retag" between edit, and flag, under a question's tags.

Comment: @wizlog Please post a screenshot. Anyone with more then 2k rep can only see the edit link, not the retag link.

Comment: Sure I'll post one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't there be a re-tag option, for community questions?

Probably not.

---

Community wiki questions are [editable by a lot more users](https://superuser.com/privileges/edit-community-wiki) than regular posts, and since you have 500+ reputation you have full editing privileges there.

Just as 2k+ users who get [full editing privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges/edit) on all posts, you lose access to the [retag option](https://superuser.com/privileges/retag-questions) on questions you can edit completely, as it would be redundant: The *edit* option **replaces** the *retag* option for 2k+ reputation users. That's also the reason for the confused comments on your question: *We 2k+ users don't have the retag link on any question*.

With 20k+ rep, it looks like this (vote to *close* is a 3k rep privilege, *protect* is 15k rep):

> [image]

If you only edit the tags using the *edit* option, it doesn't count as a full edit (e.g. towards the Editor badges).

---

You are in the unfortunate situation to have *retag* permissions, and, through suggested edits, have an *edit* link that places your changes in a queue. That's why there's both options:

- *Retag* is immediately applied, and only works for editing tags
- *Edit* is placed in a queue of suggested edits for approval by others, and can change an entire post.

Once you gain the *edit* privilege without prior approval, the *retag* link will disappear, as it's redundant.

Comment: "The edit option replaces the retag option." then why would there ever be a re-tag option?

Comment: @wizlog Because it requires more reputation to get full editing privileges, except for community wiki posts. You start with nothing, then gain the tag editing privilege and *retag* link, then that is replaced with full editing privilege and *edit* link.

Comment: I'm still not sure I fully understand... but I think its time for me to move on.

Comment: @wizlog Everything you can do in *retag* is also in *edit*. So, if you have the full *edit* option, what good is *retag*?

Comment: yes, but then I should never have the retag option.

Comment: @wizlog Do you have the edit option on questions where you also have the retag option? In my interpretation, you have retag only when you're allowed to retag, but not allowed to edit the rest of a pot.

Comment: Yes. I have both. Added another picture, of normal question.

Comment: @wizlog What can you do with the edit option on non-community wiki topics? You shouldn't have [editing](http://superuser.com/privileges/edit) privileges.

Comment: I don't.  But I still have the button.  Do you want to move to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1682/discussion-between-daniel-beck-and-wizlog)